# [swagger-codegen][php-symfony] No entrypoint in generated code?

Tags: php, symfony, silex, swagger-codegen

I am attempting to generate a `php-symfony` server stub using `swagger-codgen` but I am not getting an `index.php` (or `app.php` or anything like that).

When I generate a server stub using the `php-silex` preset I get an `index.php`. If I google "silex .htaccess" I can easily find the mod_rewrite directives to get it working. However, when I generate code using the php-symfony preset I cannot find the entry point. 
I attempted to combine the php-silex and php-symfony generated codebases (since silex is a symfony project) like so:

(index.php):

```
use Swagger\Server\Controller\GetTypesListController;

$app->GET('/image/list/types', function (Application $app, Request $request) {
    $tlc = new GetTypesListController();
    $response = $tlc->getTypeListAction($request);
    return $response;
    //new Response('How about implementing getTypeList as a GET method ?');
});
```

However, then I get errors like:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getApiHandler() on null"

I modified the `getApiHandler` function of my generated `GetTypesListController` to instantiate the `apiServer` variable:

```
public function getApiHandler()
{
    if (!isset($this->apiServer)){
        $this->apiServer = new \Swagger\Server\Api\ApiServer();
    }
    return $this->apiServer->getApiHandler('getTypesList');
}
```

but this just gave me another error:

> Undefined property: Swagger\Server\Controller\GetTypesListController::$container

(referencing `SymfonyBundle-php/Controller/Controller.php` on line 149)

I am obviously doing something wrong. I would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Edit: I do realize that I'm not supposed to call controllers inside controllers.. I assume that I'm not supposed to combine these two generated codebases at all.

Comment: Have you checked their example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/server/petstore/php-symfony/SymfonyBundle-php

Comment: I have. It is also insufficient to run on its own. I have come to realize that this code generator must be intended for an existing symfony project.